# Spacing issue with QMainwindow with centralwidget that has gridlayout

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I've coded a little Snake example.

I've created a `QMainWindow` with a `centralWidget` that has a `gridlayout`.
I can't seem to get the spacing right. I thought I can do it with `setContentMargins()`, so I placed it everywhere I can but the space still remains. I'm probably overseeing something. I think it has to do with my grid. But I don't see the problem. Thoughts?

Here is a picture: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jftcq.jpg

Here's my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qw
from PyQt5 import QtGui as qg
from PyQt5 import QtCore as qc

class Snake(qw.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Snake, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.test()
        self.show()

    def test(self):
        self.centralwidget = qw.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: green")

        self.gridLayout = qw.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.setSpacing(0)
        # self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.vLayout = qw.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.hLayout = qw.QHBoxLayout()

        self.hLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.vLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        # center the grid with stretch on both sides

        self.hLayout.addLayout(self.gridLayout)
        self.hLayout.addStretch(0)

        self.vLayout.addLayout(self.hLayout)
        # push grid to the top of the window
        self.vLayout.addStretch(0)

        self.buttons = []
        for i in range(24):
            l = []
            for j in range(24):
                b = qw.QPushButton()
                b.setFixedSize(20, 20)
                b.setStyleSheet("background-color: black")
                l.append(b)
                self.gridLayout.addWidget(b, i, j)
                self.gridLayout.setColumnMinimumWidth(j, 20)
            self.buttons.append(l)
            self.gridLayout.setRowMinimumHeight(i, 16)

        self.buttons[5][5].setStyleSheet("background-color: green")
        self.buttons[4][5].setStyleSheet("background-color: green")
        self.buttons[3][5].setStyleSheet("background-color: green")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = qw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Menu = Snake()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I tested your program but it shows fine (on Linux). It might have to do with the fact that your window is larger than your grid. You could try setting a fixed size for it.

Comment: I'm on a mac just for information, but i think i solved it.

Answer (score 0):

i think i've solved it.The clue was to recreate my grid without QHBoxLayout and QVBoxLayout.

Here's my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qw
from PyQt5 import QtGui as qg
from PyQt5 import QtCore as qc


class Snake(qw.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Snake, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.setFixedSize(20*24,20*24)
        self.test()
        self.show()


    def test(self):
        self.centralwidget = qw.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: green")
        self.centralwidget.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.gridLayout = qw.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)


        self.buttons = []
        for i in range(24):
            for j in range(24):
                b = qw.QLabel("Knopf" + str(i) + "/" + str(j))
                b.setFixedSize(20, 20)
                b.setStyleSheet("background-color: black")
                self.gridLayout.addWidget(b, i, j)
                self.gridLayout.setColumnMinimumWidth(j, 20)
            self.gridLayout.setRowMinimumHeight(i, 16)

        self.centralwidget.setLayout(self.gridLayout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = qw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Menu = Snake()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```